# java Retrieve intervals between start date and end date for 30 minutes

Tags: java

I need to retreive intervals between start date , end date for every 30 minutes.

Ex:If my start date is 2011-12-10-10:00:00 and end date is 2011-12-11-10:00:00

I need to populate the intervals between these two dates in an array.

Comment: What kind of interval are we talking about here?  Seconds, minutes, etc.?

Comment: @Phani And we're right back where we were.

Comment: Also, java and javascript are **not** the same thing.

Comment: I would start by having a look at [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```
var dates = [],
    start = new Date("2011-12-10T10:00:00Z"),
    end = new Date("2011-12-11T10:00:00Z"); // make sure the format is parsed by all browsers - or use epoch timestamps
for (var i = new Date(start); i < end; i.setMinutes(i.getMinutes()+30))
    dates.push(new Date(i));
```

Comment: +1, Pretty much what I had, except I included a string-to-date and date-to-string function so that the array was strings rather than objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  Use the [Interval.withDurationAfterStart()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#withDurationAfterStart%28org.joda.time.ReadableDuration%29) will give you an interval after the start time.  Now create a loop that adds the interval to an array, and then gets the next interval using the end time of the previous interval (until you are >= the end instant).

The resulting array will hold your interval list.